# Discontinuity in Python Boolean Priorities

Tags: python

When evaluating booleans in Python, it's said that the priority, from highest to lowest, is `not`, `and`, `or`, so why does `1 or 2 and 1/0` evaluate to 1?

My best guess is that it treats `2 and 1/0` as one side of the or statement, and since it sees 1, it short-circuits and that's it. But if so, what is the point of having a priority?

Comment: It's "precedence", not priority, and the point of precedence is to control argument grouping, not evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your confusion is about understanding what "high" and "low" precedence mean.

In your example, `1 or 2 and 1/0`, the `and` has a higher precedence than the `or`. So, the `and` part is grouped first:

```
1 or (2 and 1/0)
```

As @user2357112 says, this grouping does not imply evaluation order: the 1/0 has not yet been evaluated.

Effectively the following syntax tree has been produced:

```
    or
  /    \
1      and
      /   \
     2    1/0
```

So, as you guessed, the `or` statement is evaluated first: the evaluator can short-circuit and does not need to consider anything in the right subtree.

Comment: Great, thank you! Picturing it as a tree was very helpful!